# Nested Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $Z$ is a geometric random variable with probability of success p, and p has a beta distribution with $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=7$.  What's $E(Z)$ and $V(Z)$?

I understand that $E(Z) = q/p$ and $V(Z)=q/p^2$ where $q=1-p$ for the geometric random variable.  What I'm unsure about is how to proceed from using the beta function of $p = 56(1-x)x^6$ to calculate a definite $E(Z)$ and $V(Z)$ for geometric random variable $Z$.  Am I able to calculate a definite value?  If so, am I using the expected value of $p$?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, $p\sim\text{Beta}(2,7)$, and $Z|p\sim \text{Geom}(p)$. I will assume this geometric is over $\{0,1,2,3.\dotsc\}$ from what you stated. Remember that there are different geometrics over different possible values.Then for the expectation
\begin{align*}E[Z]&=E[E[Z|p]]\\
&=E\left[\frac{1-p}{p}\right] \\
&= \int_0^1\frac{1-p}{p}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(9)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(7)}p^{2-1}(1-p)^{7-1}\,dp \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(9)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(7)}\int_0^1p^{1-1}(1-p)^{8-1}\,dp \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(9)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(7)}\cdot \frac{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(8)}{\Gamma(9)}\\
&= 7.
\end{align*}
Can you think of how to find the variance now?

---

\begin{align*}
\text{Var}[Z] = E[\text{Var}[Z|p]]+\text{Var}[E[Z|p]]
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the law of total expectation and the law of total variance, namely
\begin{align}
E(Z) = E_{P}(E_{Z}(Z|P=p))=E_{P}(1/p) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{p^{\alpha -1} (1 - p)^{\beta -1} }{p B(\alpha, \beta)}\mathrm{d}p \,\,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Var(Z) &= E(Var(Z|P=p)) + Var(E(Z|P=p))\\
 &= E_{P}((1-p)/p^2) + Var_{P}(1/p)\\
& = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-p)p^{\alpha -1} (1 - p)^{\beta -1} }{p^2 B(\alpha, \beta)}\mathrm{d}p + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{p^{\alpha -1} (1 - p)^{\beta -1} }{p^2 B(\alpha, \beta)}\mathrm{d}p - \left( \int_{0}^{1} \frac{p^{\alpha -1} (1 - p)^{\beta -1} }{p B(\alpha, \beta)}\mathrm{d}p \right)^2\, .
\end{align}